# How to refine a logistics population model?

Tags: regression, forecasting, estimation, modeling, logistic-curve

I have to refine a logistic population model so that it more accurately fits a set of data and was wondering how to do this. The only way I can find is to use a variable carrying capacity however I can't wrap my head around this.

This is the data I'm using, the timeframe is from 1810-2010. http://www.populstat.info/Europe/francec.htm

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: I find the question perfectly clear. Can you please un-flag it, so that I can answer.

Comment: As far I could see, you have 2 waves of logistic growth: one from 26'000 in 1750 up to 38'000 in 1900 (center 1827), followed by an additional 23'000 person niche (center 1969-1970). You have two drops in the curve, in 1918 and 1944, like it is often the case at change of logistic waves. [See: Chaoslike states can be expected before and after logistic growth, Th. Modis, A. Debecker, Technological Forecasting and Social Change (vol 41), 1992].

Comment: I also find the question clear, the request by @AlainD to release the hold so that he can answer makes sense to me.